# How to make a Flask app with https on digital ocean

Tags: python, nginx, flask, digital-ocean

I have a flask app running on port 8000 of digital oceans' droplet. I needed to implement https on this server, and i followed this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

With that, my 'mydomain.com' has https, but 'mydomain.com:8000' doesn't. 
I've tried to put

```
    listen 8000 ssl;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl;
    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
}
```

on my nginx congif, but still doesn't work. With this code above, I can't start my flask app because the port 8000 it's already been used from nginx process

My full config file is like this:

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl;
    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = www.funders-api.ninja) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = funders-api.ninja) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Why would nginx listen on port 8000? Can you post your nginx configuration too?

Comment: I actually don't know. Without it, my port 8000 gets no certificate error. Here's my full config(I think that is this file that you refer to) https://pastebin.com/Z40Rqh50

Comment: Edit your question and paste the config into it please. You will not attract many answers this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 1 application/service may be listening to 1 concrete port.

If your flask app is already listening to port 8000, nginx can't.

Normal https connections enter through port 443.

I would change the configuration to:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

}
```

Like this, secure conection enters through port 443, gets validated by nginx with the certificates

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

And then you make a proxy to the port which your flask app is listening to (once the connection has been secured).

This is an example on how I'd do it. If nginx is the one to process the connection with the certificate, it's nginx that needs to listen to the port you make the connection, and then proxy the connection to your flask app.

If your request is made directly to the flask app, nginx doesn't do anything, as the connection has not gone through it.

If you have any questions don't doubt on asking me.